# ¿Como remplazar una linea en un archivo?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy practicando con leer y escribir en un archivo en c# con el siguiente código:

```
private void buttonWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            StreamWriter writer = File.AppendText("mensaje.txt");
            writer.Write("Hola");
            writer.Flush();
            writer.Close();
        }
        catch(Exception error)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(error);
        }
    }


private void buttonRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {            
        StreamReader reader = File.OpenText("mensaje.txt");
        string data = null;
        labelmensaje.Text = "";
        while ((data = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {                
            labelmensaje.Text += data;
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
```

Me pregunto como remplazar la linea ya escrita en el archivo, ya que de este modo si vuelvo a escribir la cadena nueva se suma a la ya escrita:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe como arreglar eso?

Comment: si haces labelmensaje.Text += data;, esta agregando data a la propiedad text. si solo queres reemplazarla, hace labelmensaje.Text = data;

Comment: Sigue sumando las cadenas, creo que el detalle debe estar al escribir en el archivo, ya que no se como eliminar el dato existente para después escribir el nuevo.

Comment: Estas haciendo appendtext, por lo tanto, estas agregando. Si queres un nuevo archivo, seria create

Comment: Supongo entonces que no se puede modificar el contenido de un archivo sin remplazarlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrias hacerlo muy simple si usas el

[File.WriteAllText Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.5)

este comenta

> Crea un archivo nuevo, escribe el contenido en el archivo y, a continuación, lo cierra. Si el archivo de destino ya existe, se sobrescribe.

entonces el codigo quedaria

```
private void buttonWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {

        string texto = "Hola";
        File.WriteAllText("mensaje.txt", texto);

    }
    catch(Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

escribes directo el contenido en el archivo reemplazandolo

Answer (score 1):

Si solo vas a crear un archivo sumamente simple podrías utilizar otros métodos como **`WriteAllText`** y **`ReadAllText`**.
Cuando utilizas **`AppendText`** es para agregar más información al documento.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
private void buttonWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllText("mensaje.txt", "Hola");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}

private void buttonRead_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        labelmensaje.Text = File.ReadAllText("mensaje.txt");
    }
    catch (Exception error)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(error);
    }
}
```

> [File.WriteAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=netframework-4.7.2): Crea un archivo nuevo, escribe el contenido en
>   el archivo y, a continuación, lo cierra. Si el archivo de destino ya
>   existe, se sobrescribe.
>
> [File.ReadAllText](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2): Abre un archivo de texto, lee todo el texto del
>   archivo en una cadena y, a continuación, cierra el archivo.